# Predefined module aliases in Python?

Tags: python

I'm developing a library of Python modules that is fairly deeply nested, e.g.:

```
\MyTools
    __init__.py
    \HydroTools
        __init__.py
        \bin
        \Code
            __init__.py
            hydro.py
    \TerraTools 
        __init__.py
       \bin
       \Code
           __init__.py
           terra.py
```

Is there some way to define aliases for the modules ahead of time (maybe by modifying **init**.py?), so that instead of importing with...

```
from MyTools.HydroTools.Code import hydro
from MyTools.TerraTools.Code import terra
```

...I could do something cleaner like

```
from MyTools import hydro, terra
```

Comment: If you import `hydro` and `terra` in the `MyTools` `__init__.py`, they can then be imported from `MyTools` like you want.

Comment: yes, in your top level `__init__.py` you would add the exact imports you use now with a dot at the beginning: `from .MyTools.HydroTools.Code import hydro` then it is available from the top level package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to push these nested packages on top of your module namespace.

In `MyTools/__init__.py` add:

```
from .HydroTools.Code import hydro
from .TerraTools.Code import terra
```